# Function to calculate Precision, Recall and Accuracy for 5 different algorithms in R

Tags: r, algorithm, function, precision-recall

I have 4 different datasets in this general form:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(319, 77, 222, 107, 167),
                  var2 = c(137, 290, 237, 52, 192),
                  class = c(1,1,0,1,0))
```

Each containing var1, var2 and a class variable.  I was given the following instructions:

Write an R script that takes a data table as input and returns the performance statistics (precision, recall, and accuracy) for the five difference algorithms, decision trees (rpart), naive Bayes (naiveBayes), K nearest neighbor (knn) , support vector machines (svm) and artificial neural networks (nnet). The return value of the script will be a 5 by 3 matrix of the statistics for each algorithm. For knn use k=3, for svm, using the linear kernel and for nnet use 4 hidden nodes. To calculate the statistics you will be using 10 fold cross validation.

Essentially, I believe I have to write an all encompassing function that I can pass a dataframe, and the return of that function is the precision, recall and accuracy for each of the 5 different algorithms outlined in the directions above.  Is there a concise way to perform this??  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to train the models? If so, you're basically asking someone to do a whole assignment for you. There's lots of resources to find help coding up [kfold cross validation](https://www.r-bloggers.com/cross-validation-for-predictive-analytics-using-r/). Try to write a function, something like `function(validation_data, model)`, and extract the predicted values for the model and calculate the metrics you want. Extracted predicted values is different for the different models, so that is likely what your assignment is testing you on. Look into using S3 methods and generic functions

Comment: @astrofunkswag Sorry I wasn't clear.  Yes I have to train the models and predict on test data.  I was looking for a function I could use inside my user created function for these 5 algorithms.  I think I found it.  The train function in the caret package I believe can do all the algorithms necessary.  I came up with a function that only has one argument, the df, and inside the function it splits the df into train/test sets, performs model fits for each of the 5 algorithms, predicts using each model on test data, then adds precision, recall and accuracy to a matrix and returns the matrix.

Comment: I just extract precision, recall and accuracy from the confusionMatrix function for each algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the class variable is the 3rd column and named "class", which it is with all my example datasets, here is what I came up with:

```
algStats <- function(dataset){
  # Split data into test and train (80/20 train to test)
  trainindex  <- sample(1:nrow(dataset), 0.8 * nrow(dataset))
  TrainData  <- dataset[trainindex, ] # Train data length same for all datasets
  TestData <- dataset[-trainindex, ] # Test data length same for all datasets
  # Declare 10-fold CV (same for all datasets)
  train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
  # Train a decision tree model
  DecTreeMod <- train(as.factor(class)~., data=TrainData, 
                       trControl=train_control, method="rpart")
  # Predict on test data using Decision Tree model
  DecTreepred <- predict(DecTreeMod, TestData[,1:2])
  # Create confusion matrix for Decision Tree classifier
  DecTreecf <- confusionMatrix(DecTreepred, as.factor(TestData[,3]), mode = "prec_recall", positive = "1")
  # Extract Precision, Recall and Accuracy from confusion matrix
  DecTreePrecision <- DecTreecf$byClass[5] # <-----Precision
  DecTreeRecall <- DecTreecf$byClass[6] # <-----Recall
  DecTreeAcc <- DecTreecf$overall[1] # <-----Accuracy

  # Create an empty matrix to hold performance measures of each algorithm
  rownames = c("Decision Tree", "Naive Bayes", "KNN", "SVM", "ANN")
  colnames = c("Precision", "Recall", "Accuracy")

  performance <- matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 5,
     byrow = T, dimnames = list(rownames, colnames))

  # Append the metrics from the Decision Tree classifier into the matrix
  # performance <- rbind(performance, c(DecTreePrecision,DecTreeRecall,DecTreeAcc))
  performance[1,] <- c(DecTreePrecision,DecTreeRecall,DecTreeAcc)

  # Train a Naive Bayes model
  NBMod <- train(as.factor(class)~., data=TrainData, 
                      trControl=train_control, method="nb")
  # Predict on test data using Naive Bayes model
  NBpred <- predict(NBMod, TestData[,1:2])
  # Create confusion matrix for Naive Bayes classifier
  NBcf <- confusionMatrix(NBpred, as.factor(TestData[,3]), mode = "prec_recall", positive = "1")
  # Extract Precision, Recall and Accuracy from confusion matrix
  NBPrecision <- NBcf$byClass[5] # <-----Precision
  NBRecall <- NBcf$byClass[6] # <-----Recall
  NBAcc <- NBcf$overall[1] # <-----Accuracy

  # Append the metrics from the Naive Bayes classifier into the matrix
  performance[2,] <- c(NBPrecision,NBRecall,NBAcc)

  # Train a KNN model
  KNNMod <- train(as.factor(class)~., data=TrainData, tuneGrid = expand.grid(k = 3), 
                 trControl=train_control, method="knn", preProcess = c("center","scale"))
  # Predict on test data using KNN model
  KNNpred <- predict(KNNMod, TestData[,1:2])
  # Create confusion matrix for KNN classifier
  KNNcf <- confusionMatrix(KNNpred, as.factor(TestData[,3]), mode = "prec_recall", positive = "1")
  # Extract Precision, Recall and Accuracy from confusion matrix
  KNNPrecision <- KNNcf$byClass[5] # <-----Precision
  KNNRecall <- KNNcf$byClass[6] # <-----Recall
  KNNAcc <- KNNcf$overall[1] # <-----Accuracy

  # Append the metrics from the KNN classifier into the matrix
  performance[3,] <- c(KNNPrecision,KNNRecall,KNNAcc)

  # Train an SVM model
  SVMMod <- train(as.factor(class)~., data=TrainData, 
                  trControl=train_control, method="svmLinear", preProcess = c("center","scale"))
  # Predict on test data using the SVM model
  SVMpred <- predict(SVMMod, TestData[,1:2])
  # Create confusion matrix for SVM classifier
  SVMcf <- confusionMatrix(SVMpred, as.factor(TestData[,3]), mode = "prec_recall", positive = "1")
  # Extract Precision, Recall and Accuracy from confusion matrix
  SVMPrecision <- SVMcf$byClass[5] # <-----Precision
  SVMRecall <- SVMcf$byClass[6] # <-----Recall
  SVMAcc <- SVMcf$overall[1] # <-----Accuracy

  # Append the metrics from the SVM classifier into the matrix
  performance[4,] <- c(SVMPrecision,SVMRecall,SVMAcc)

  # Train an ANN model
  ANNMod <- train(as.factor(class)~., data=TrainData, tuneGrid = expand.grid(
            size = 4, decay = 0.1), linear.output = F, trControl=train_control, method="nnet",
            preProcess = c("center","scale"))
  # Predict on test data using the ANN model
  ANNpred <- predict(ANNMod, TestData[,1:2])
  # Create confusion matrix for ANN classifier
  ANNcf <- confusionMatrix(ANNpred, as.factor(TestData[,3]), mode = "prec_recall", positive = "1")
  # Extract Precision, Recall and Accuracy from confusion matrix
  ANNPrecision <- ANNcf$byClass[5] # <-----Precision
  ANNRecall <- ANNcf$byClass[6] # <-----Recall
  ANNAcc <- ANNcf$overall[1] # <-----Accuracy

  # Append the metrics from the ANN classifier into the matrix
  performance[5,] <- c(ANNPrecision,ANNRecall,ANNAcc)

  # Return the performance matrix
  return(performance)
}
```